# How to print an URL with HTML using sprintf()

Tags: php, html, printf

I'm trying to use sprintf() to print some text which includes an URL with some HTML tags. How can I achieve that?

For example;

```
$txt_string = 'GENERAL TEXT <a href="URL" target="_blank" rel="noopener">linked text</a> MORE TEXT.';
```

How can I use sprintf to print that without including HTML inside $txt_string?

I'll try to be more specific. I want to pass that URL as an argument on sprintf(), but that's not the problem. The problem is that HTML that's going to format that URL. Is there an easy way to remove that HTML from inside $txt_string and put it elsewhere? The expected result is just a normal text string with that URL.

Comment: Do you want to replace URL with the actual url or.. what is it that you wanna do?

Comment: `echo sprintf($txt_string);`

Comment: Show your exact expected output.  Show what you've tried. You want to `strip_tags`?  Have you researched before posting a question?  Your question is Unclear.

Comment: Very UnClear what you are actually trying to do. Please add more details to your question. Example input and output is a great idea, remember we are not looking over your shoulder so we have no idea what you are trying to do unless you make it clear to us

Comment: @mickmackusa Sure let me have a look

Comment: Sorry guys, I'll try to be more specific. I want to pass that URL as an argument on sprintf(), but that's not the problem. The problem is that HTML that's going to format that URL. Is there an easy way to remove that HTML from inside $txt_string and put it elsewhere? The expected result is just a normal text string with that URL.

Comment: @d3vcho plese update your question to include all relevant details.  Do not add question details as comments.  We want the full story -- all in one place.

Comment: @d3vcho Please post in your question THE EXACT OUTPUT that you want.

Comment: @mickmackusa I would be tempted to answer it. Its an odd senario capturing 2 database rows of information in one row of the html form. And of course overwriting a string containing a query

Comment: @mickmackusa Hope you dont mind, I saw no answer appear from you so I gave it a shot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do just that with `sprintf()` and format the given variable(s).

```
$link = filter_var( 'http://example.com',  FILTER_SANITIZE_URL );

$format_link = '<a href="'. $link .'" target="_blank" rel="noopener">linked text</a>';

$txt_string = sprintf( 
    "GENERAL TEXT %s MORE TEXT.",
    $format_link
);

echo $txt_string;
```